# Facebook iOS Auth without app switching

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

Our iOS app currently uses basic Facebook authentication to get user profile info. When the user taps on authenticate, the app does a fast switch between the Facebook App and our app to authenticate.

We would like to avoid the fast switch and remain in our app while we authenticate the user with FB. We noticed that this was done nicely on the [Beats Music](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/beats-music/id781817640?mt=8) app for iOS.

Thanks in advance,
AppsXpress

Comment: If you use Facebook SDK, this is the only way. If you want to avoid this, you need to be using the Social Framework from iOS

Comment: I realized this with LinkedIn Authentication using a UIWebView, I haven't tried with Facebook SDK to be honest, but I think it is possible as well.